# how to fix Warning: Use of undefined constant _ - assumed '_' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: functions

Warning: Use of undefined constant _ - assumed '_' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in D:\xampp\htdocs\keuangan_rs\aksi_konten.php on line 52

```
elseif($aksi=="edit" AND $_POST['submit']){ 
    $nama = $_POST['nama_projek']; 
    $lokasi = $_POST['lokasi']; 
    $item = $_POST['item_pekerjaan']; 
    $nilai = $_POST['nilai_projek']; 
    $owner = $_POST['owner']; 
    $inisial = strtoupper($_POST['inisial_owner']); 
    $pic_owner = $_POST['pic_owner']; 
    $tanggal = $_POST['tanggal']; 
    $lama = $_POST['lama_pekerjaan']; 
    $file = $_FILES['gambar']['name']; 
    $acak = rand(1,99); 
    $filename = $acak._.$file; -------------------->online 52
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies in this line:

```
$filename = $acak._.$file;
```

It should be

```
$filename = $acak.'_'.$file;
```

Comment: not going work @Krzysiek Dróżdż. Any thing matter

Comment: @SutanIlhamsyahSiregar well, it will work, because you want to use these 2 variables as strings and concatenate them using "_" as divider. You can't concatenate variables with `_`, because there is no such constant in PHP.